# Using beta features with the Google Dataproc Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using Google Dataproc along with a Java application managing the provisioning of clusters and submitting of jobs.

Recently I noticed an interesting beta feature "Scheduled Deletion". I'm now looking into how I can take advantage of it.

I'm using the 1.25.0 Java API and not surprisingly it does not have getters/setters/objects defined for these beta features. So I figured I'd just use the set(field, value) on GenericJson work around it.

But... discovered that there does not seem to be a way to point the Dataproc API at a different version path.

```java
private static final String REST_PATH = "v1/projects/{projectId}/regions/{region}/clusters/{clusterName}";
```

Anyway, hope I'm missing something and I can try this feature out without too much hackery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is separate package for v1beta2 API:

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/dataproc/v1beta2/java/latest/

Since `v1beta2` is a preview of what will appear in `v1` you should be able to search/replace package names and things will just work.